# Navigation Drawer with multiple fragments in same screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

I have created an `activity` name `HomePageActivity` in this `activity` have designed xml and in this layout file i am loading data with the help of multiple fragments.

Here is the layout file of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/homePageBackground"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/announcementHomefragment"
    android:name="in.app.AnnouncementFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/homePageBackground" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/homePageBackground" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newsTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/new_list"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/newshomefragment"
            android:name="in.app.NewsFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/newsTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/newshomefragment"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/product_in_home"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/proCategoryhomefragment"
            android:name="in.app.CategoryFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/productTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trainingTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/proCategoryhomefragment"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/trainings_in_home"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/trainingfragment"
            android:name="in.app.TrainingFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/trainingTitle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my main activity layout file. how can i add navigation drawer on this. Please help me to get this done.

***TRIED CODE:***

**LAYOUT FILE:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/homePageBackground"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#181818"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/announcementHomefragment"
    android:name="in.app.AnnouncementFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/homePageBackground" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/homePageBackground" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newsTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/new_list"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/newshomefragment"
            android:name="in.app.NewsFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/newsTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/newshomefragment"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/product_in_home"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/proCategoryhomefragment"
            android:name="in.app.CategoryFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/productTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trainingTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/proCategoryhomefragment"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/trainings_in_home"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/trainingfragment"
            android:name="in.app.TrainingFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/trainingTitle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity Code:**

```
public class HomePageActivity extends Activity {
public static String cookie;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
ActionBar actionBar;
Editor editSharedPreferences;
// private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
Activity activity;
private static String trackerId;
Tracker t;
private static Boolean isPitchAlreadyRunning;

List<String> dataList;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    activity = (Activity) HomePageActivity.this;
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    trackerId = getResources().getString(R.string.tracker_id);
    t = ((GoogleAnalyticsApplication) getApplication())
            .getTracker(GoogleAnalyticsApplication.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    // Force to the Application to show the Action Overflow
    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class
                .getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Ignore
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);

    dataList.add("Announcement");
    dataList.add("Profile");
    dataList.add("Logout");

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        SelectItem(0);
    }

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(
            BConstant.B_LOGIN_CHECK, BConstant.PRIVATE_MODE);
    cookie = sharedPreferences.getString(
            BConstant.WEB_SERVICES_COOKIES, "");
    Boolean isFromSplashScreen = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(
            BConstant.FROM_SPLASH_SCREEN, false);
    editSharedPreferences = sharedPreferences.edit();

    if (isFromSplashScreen) {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,
                R.anim.slide_out_left);
        editSharedPreferences.putBoolean(BConstant.FROM_SPLASH_SCREEN,
                false);
        editSharedPreferences.commit();
    }
    isPitchAlreadyRunning = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(
            BConstant.IS_PITCH_ALREADY_RUNNING, false);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.landing_page);

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
    // Get an Analytics tracker to report app starts & uncaught exceptions
    // etc.
    if (!trackerId.equals(BConstant.DEFAULT_TRACKERID)) {
        t.setScreenName("Home Page");

        t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);
    // Stop the analytics tracking
    if (!trackerId.equals(BConstant.DEFAULT_TRACKERID))
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isPitchAlreadyRunning = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(
            BConstant.IS_PITCH_ALREADY_RUNNING, false);
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem pitchStartedMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.pitchStratInTraining);
    if (!isPitchAlreadyRunning) {
        pitchStartedMenu.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        pitchStartedMenu.setVisible(true);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Some logic is here
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Some logic here
    return true;
}

public void SelectItem(int possition) {

    switch (possition) {
    case 0:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomePageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    default:

        break;
    }

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
    // set the title of the page
    // setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

}
```

}

Comment: Where is your navigation drawer code? And as far as I know, it is impossible. I even checked google play store which even didn't have both of them on same. I tried alot but the itemonclicklistner doesn't work. Looking for the correct answers

Comment: [Tried?](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=navigation+drawer+sample+android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=JJbgU5noBMzV8gfjiIDQCA)

Comment: dont expect others to give you code. try implementing navigation drawyer yourself first and if you run into problems searched and tried solutions then ask a question

Comment: let me paste what i have already tried

Comment: @IllegalArgument please have a look on my updated question

Comment: @MysticMagic have a look on this

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following...

Use a standard `DrawerLayout` layout file as your `Activity` layout file, in other words just the following...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#181818"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Create a new class which extends Fragment (call it MainFragment for example). Use the layout fie you originally had for your `Activity` (the one with the `ScrollView`) as the layout for MainFragment.

In your `Activity` create an instance of `MainFragment` and use `FragmentManager` with a `FragmentTransaction` to add `MainFragment` to the `FrameLayout` of the `Activity` layout (the one with @+id/content_frame).

Doing this would mean your `Activity` would only have one `FrameLayout` containing a single `Fragment` (your MainFragment) but that `Fragment` would then be the parent of all of the other views (`ScrollView` and `TextViews` and child `Fragments`).

Comment: @Squnok how can i use fragments inside fragment?

Comment: @rup35h : Nested `Fragments` are allowed. I'm not 100% sure it will work with your layout file though but give it a try. If it doesn't then replace the `<fragment ... />` declarations with `FrameLayouts` instead and use `getChildFragmentManager()` in your MainFragment to create instances of the `Fragments` and add them to the `FrameLayouts` using `FragmentTransactions`

Comment: read this tutorial carefully:http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/